# Orchard: how to persist a record without content

Tags: orchardcms

Allright, this should be fairly easy.

I would like to persist some records for my module in Orchard (1.7.2) without those records being also a ContentPartRecord.

In other words, I would like to be able to persist in DB the following objects:

```
public class LogItemRecord
{
    public virtual string Message { get; set; }
}
```

..which is already mapped on to the db. But notice that this class is not derived from ContentPartRecord, as it is most certainly not one.

However, when I call IRepository instance's .Create method, all I get is a lousy nHibernate exception:

*No persister for: MyModule.Models.LogItemRecord*

...which disappears if I *do* declare the LogItem record as having been inherited from ContentPartRecord, but trying to persist that, apart from being hacky-tacky, runs into an exception of its own, where nHibernate again justly complains that the Id value for the record is zero, though in not so many words.

So... how do I play nicely with Orchard and use its API to persist objects of my own that are not ContentParts / ContentItems?

Comment: Have you created a table in the database using Migrations.cs to store that object?

Comment: Yes, I have. The question is how to persist the object without inheriting the record from ContentPartRecord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running 1.7.3 (also tested in 1.7.2) and have successfully been able to persist the following class to the DB:

```
public class ContactRecord
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Here are the relevant lines from `Migrations.cs`

```
SchemaBuilder.CreateTable(
    typeof(ContactRecord).Name,
    table => table
        .Column<int>("Id", col => col.Identity().PrimaryKey())
        .Column<string>("Name")
        .Column<string>("JobTitle")
        .Column<string>("Email")
        .Column<string>("Phone")
);
```

I'm going to assume that the code you've shown for `LogItemRecord` is the complete class definition when making the following statement...

I think that any Record class you store in the DB **needs an `Id` property**, and that property should be marked as `Identity` and `PrimaryKey` in the table definition (as I've done above).

When you create a `*Record` class which inherits from `ContentPartRecord` and setup the table like

```
SchemaBuilder.CreateTable(
    "YourRecord",
    table => table
       .ContentPartRecord()
       // more column definitions
);
```

then you get the `Id` property/PK "for free" by inheritance and calling `.ContentPartRecord()` in the Migration.

See the [PersonRecord](https://orchardtrainingdemo.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Models/PersonRecord.cs) in the [Orchard Training Demo Module](https://orchardtrainingdemo.codeplex.com/) for another example of storing a standard class as a record in the DB.

Comment: The missing Id property was just it! Entity Framework expects an Id property by convention; apparently NHibernate does not do this. Thanks!